# What do I need to do to rsync on Windows to make it keep special characters in filenames on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, rsync, character-encoding

We're in the process of implementing an offsite backup of all our servers to a remote Linux server.  We're using `rsync` over SSH.  What I've found is that characters such as ñ, ö, ô and ã  are replaced on the Linux server with underscores.  I don't mind if it changes these characters in the filenames of documents, but when it renames a language pack from `Español.clx` to `Espa_ol.clx`, it could cause issues for us further down the line.

My current command-line is:

```
rsync -v -rlt -z --chmod=a=rw,Da+x -u --delete -e "ssh -i <keyfile>" <source> <destination>
```

What do I need to do differently to make the special characters copy over correctly?

EDIT:  For the initial sync which will take place locally, before the machine is moved offsite, I have SAMBA enabled.  I am able to copy files from Windows to the Samba share, retaining the original filename, though it looks different in the Linux directory listing, i.e. `têst` becomes `tÃªst`.
These files get deleted by rsync when it runs, as it does not match the filenames.

Comment: This question http://superuser.com/questions/91967/rsync-character-set-problems is similar, but not relevant. I'm not mounting the Windows share in Linux, rather using the rsync client on the Windows machine directly.

Comment: take a look at rsyncs --iconv option

Comment: When I use --iconv=utf-16, which is, as I understand it, the encoding that windows uses, rsync dies with:

[sender] cannot convert filename: . (Invalid argument)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the parameter

```
--iconv=ISO-8859-1,utf-8
```

seems to have sorted the problem out.

Answer (score 1):

I got files with weird characters to work using cygwin's rsync 3.1.2, installed via `setup-x86_64.exe`, and NOT DeltaCopy's rsync, which seems to use an outdated `cygwin1.dll`.